# strange results in adding double numbers

Tags: java, math, double

I began read about Java programming these days, and I find something strange in simple code

```
double sum= 0.012 + 0.012+ 0.012;
        System.out.println("the value is" + sum);
```

the output is. 0.036000000000000004

but if I add 0.12 + 0.12 + 0.12
the result is 0.36
why?

Comment: Google `Floating point error`

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: The *really* strange part: how many people using floating point numbers out there; without bothering to **understand** the concept they are using. Hint: when you are newbie, *anything* you stumble upon ... has been asked. Here. And elsewhere. A thousand times. And answered.

Comment: @GhostCat okay but I recently noticed that multiplication doesn't work in java :)